# Why do i get this error by installing Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, installation

If i try to install Tkinter i get this
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter
My python version is 3.10.7
How can i fix this ?

Comment: [You cannot install tkinter with `pip`.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22No+matching+distribution+found+for+tkinter%22)

Comment: tkinter cannot be installed via `pip`.  For Windows platform, you need to select it when installing Python. For Linux platform, you need to install it via system package tool.

Comment: I runned a python script and i get No module named 'Tkinter'   I installed it now during the installtion.

Comment: The library is called `tkinter`, not `Tkinter`. It was called `Tkinter` in Python 2, but I don't assume you still use Python 2, since it's dead since the beginning of 2020.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Python 3 version prior to Python 3.7, or a non-standard version of Python 3 that does not include Tkinter, do the following:

On a Linux System:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

On a Windows or Mac System:

The simplest and easiest method to install Tkinter, is to either:

Install the latest version of ***ActiveTcl***, or
Install the latest version of ***ActivePython***

Comment: But you don't need it, cause tkinter comes pre-installed with python distribution.